# Angular: How to populate a dynamic array for select using ngOptions?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Ideally, I want to populate the array via computed property. For example,

```
    Object.defineProperty(MyObj.prototype, 'linkedList', {
        get: function () {
            var list = [];
            this.dataList.forEach(function (cs) {
                if (cs !== this) {
                    list.push(cs.name);
                }
            });
            return list;
        }
    });
```

However, if I used this computed property as select options like

```
<select data-ng-model="name" data-ng-options="g for g in myObj.linkedList"></select>
```

I will get this error:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

In fact, I still get this error even if I return a fixed list like:

```
    Object.defineProperty(MyObj.prototype, 'linkedList', {
        get: function () {
            return ['test1', 'test2'];
        }
    });
```

However, it is okay if I return a static array:

```
MyObj._linkedList = ['test1', 'test2'];

  Object.defineProperty(MyObj.prototype, 'linkedList', {
        get: function () {
            return MyObj._linkedList;
        }
    });
```

I also tried to use a filter in the ngOptions and the same error is thrown. Why and How?

UPDATE:

As it turns out, my original question above doesn't truly reflect the problem, because the problem happens only if I use a directive. To simplify the question, I removed the directive part.

Anyway, in my directive, I have

```
    scope: {
        name: '=',
        isEditing: '=',
        isHidden: '=',
        options: '='
    }

<div>
    <div data-ng-hide="!isHidden" style="background-color: lightgrey">&nbsp;</div>
    <div data-ng-show="!isEditing && !isHidden">{{name}}</div>
    <select class="select-input"  data-ng-show="isEditing && !isHidden" data-ng-model="name" data-ng-options="g for g in {{options}}"><option value=""></option></select>
</div>
```

Here is how to use it:

```
<td><ms-table-select-cell name="myObj.link" is-editing="myObj.isEditing" options="myObj.linkedList" /></td>
```

This is how the error occurs. If I directly use the select tag with ngOptions, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your 'get' property is called at each loop.
You can try to assign the variable value once and then loop on it.

```
<select data-ng-model="name" data-ng-options="g for g in myArray = myObj.linkedList"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip, although it doesn't fix my problem. However, as I figured out, this is actually only a problem if I pass myObj.linkedList as a directive parameter. If I use it directly, there is no problem. see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case every time angular calls myObj.linkedList it gets a new object, so angular repeatedly begin new digest cycle and does it untill the number of iterations exceeds 10 - than it throw an error "10 $digest() iterations reached".

To avoid this you must construct your code so that every call to the myObj.linkedList returns the same object.

Try to move the `var list = [];` expression out of the `Object.defineProperty` call.

I prepared 2 fiddles:
[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/ye7cJ/4/) - with the Error
[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/ye7cJ/5/) - without the Error and with tiny modification.

Compare them.
Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. With your help, I almost made it work. Simply moving var list = [] outside of the function will make it static. I had to create an instance variable to hold it. Now, the problem is that I have to reset this array when another property changes. So, it's much more involved. The fact that this happens only if I use a directive, it must be a defect in angular, right?

Comment: Okay, I managed to reset the list when the dependent property changes. However, to my surprise, the select options do not update the list, although, through debugger, I can see it changed, but somehow the directive doesn't take it. If I don't use the directive, it just works fine. This is another struggle leading me to ask is angular really so great? Also, during this process, I realize a potential performance issue of angular...myObj.linkedList function is unnecessarily called too many times.

Comment: May be I could help with the current issue if you prepare a fiddle for it

Comment: Okay, I extended your fiddle a little bit at http://jsfiddle.net/miliu99/g96w2/2/, but it is not fully working. As you can see, my idea is if the first select box chooses 'fruit', the second select box should only show 'apple' and 'pear'.